# Shallow Copy, Map and Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, shallow-copy

I am trying to understand how shallow copy works with `map` and without `map` on an array.

```js
const arr = [
 {
   name: 'example',
   inner: {
     title: 'test'
   }
 }

]
const copy = arr.map(a => ({
  ...a
}))

copy[0].name = 'name1'
copy[0].inner.title = 'title1'
```

Updating `name` prop on the `copy` will not affect the original array `arr`. However, updating `inner.title` will modify both `copy` and `arr`. As far as I understand, in a shallow copy only top/first level props are copied, nested objects still share the same reference.

However, now  if I create a shallow copy without using `map` then even the first/top level props will share the same reference I think or at least updating first/top level props on the copy will affect the original one.

```js
// same arr above

const copy2 = [...arr];
copy2[0].name = 'name2';
copy2[0].inner.title = 'title2';
```

Now, the original `arr`'s `name` value is 'name2' and `inner.title` value is 'title2'. Why is that? What is the exact difference between two code snippets, how `map` plays a role in shallow copy?

Comment: In the `map` example you're doing something different; you're destructing each entrys' object properties ("going one level deeper"). In the `...` example you're not doing that. The equivalent would be a `map` and returning `a`.

Comment: `copy2` is a shallow copy of the array - so `copy2` is a different reference from `arr`. But the objects contained within each are still the same references (because the copy is shallow). Whereas `copy` consists of shallow copies of each object in the array (and the array itself is also a different reference). Note how `copy2` uses "array spread" `[...arr]` while `copy` uses "object spread" on each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to start with your `copy2` as that's simpler. When you do this:

```
const copy2 = [...arr];
```

that is use the "spread" operator on an array, you make exactly a "shallow copy" of the array. This means that `copy2` and `arr` are references to different arrays (arrays that are in different memory locations, if you want to think of it that way, although memory management is just an implementation detail of the JS engine rather than something JS developers have to think about), but their contents, if they are objects (which they are here) are still referencing the same things. That is `arr[0]` and `copy2[0]` are literally the same object - in the same memory location, if you want to think of it that way - and mutating one will mutate the other just the same (as your code snippet and its result proves).

`copy` though is doing something rather different:

```
const copy = arr.map(a => ({
  ...a
}))
```

While you're also using the "spread" operator to here to again make "shallow copies", *what it is that you're copying* is different. It's not the array you're copying - it's `a`, which stands for an element of the array. (This affects all elements because that's what `map` does.) So what you're doing here is making a new array called `copy`, that isn't a reference to any previously existing array, whose elements are shallow copies of the corresponding elements in `a`. Which is why changing `copy[0].name` doesn't affect `arr[0].name`, because those 2 objects are references to different things - due to the shallow copy.

TLDR: the key difference is that in `copy2` it's the whole array that you've made a shallow copy of, and because it's shallow, mutations to its object elements mutate the elements of the original. Whereas with `copy` you've actually shallowly copied each individual element in in, thereby going "one level deeper" if you like.

Comment: Side question. if `copy2` was a real deep clone of the `arr`, then what would you tell me about their references? They will reference to different arrays or the same array in the memory location?

Comment: different arrays, of course. If they referenced the same array then their contents couldn't be different. And by defining `copy2 = arr.map(someFunction)`, `copy2` is necessarily its own array, not a reference to `arr`, because `.map` always returns a new array.